# Parsing URL string in into JSON keeps retuning blank object

Tags: jquery, json

I can't fingure out why this code doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    $(".alertDeleteButton").click(function(e) {

        var str = $(this).attr("href");
        alert(str);

        var obj = str.split("&").reduce(function(prev, curr, i, arr) {
            var p = curr.split("=");
            prev[decodeURIComponent(p[0])] = decodeURIComponent(p[1]);
            return prev;
        }, {});

        alert(obj);


        e.preventDefault(); 
    });

});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/madcaesar/b2XpN/)

All I want to do, is use the string in in a link when pressed by a user and create a json object.

{"userdeleteid": "55", "dayid": "55"}. etc...

I've searched and found about 3 different ways to do it, and they ALL give me the [object Object] result.

[I wanted to implement this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2880929/1245564), but it seems to only look at the URL in the browser, I want it to look at the value of the link via (this).attr("href");

Comment: `alert()` prints strings so it needs to convert the object to string. You should debug with Firebug's console or your browser's equivalent tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use JSON.stringify(), like this:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Comment: God damn it, I've literary spent the last 3 hours on this, refusing the ask a question on here because I was sure the answer was right in front of me... All 3 versions that I got to work and only got [object Object] WORK, I just needed your line. Thank you for saving my sanity!

Answer (score 1):

You can use **JSON.stringify** available as part of the modern browser API If you are dealing with old browsers please refer JSON 2 (Third party support library).

[image]